# Get file returned from REST POST request with robot framework requests library

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, robotframework

I am testing a REST server; one of its services provides a file in response. I use `robotframework-requests` library for calling the service. This is my test-case:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             RequestsLibrary


*** Test Cases ***
Test
    RequestsLibrary.CREATE SESSION      session     http://192.168.100.139:9090
    ${data} =       evaluate    json.load(open('/root/data.json', 'r'))   json
    log to console  Data: ${data}
    ${resp} =       RequestsLibrary.POST REQUEST    session  uri=/omc/simulator/api/generate   data=${data}
    log to console  Resp: ${resp}
```

This is what I get in return:

```
Data: {u'files': [{u'tags': [{u'name': u'l1', u'value': u'l2', u'level': 2}], u'counters': {u'count': 10, u'valueMin': 0, u'prefix': u'a1', u'specifics': [{u'valueMin': 0, u'valueMax': 10, u'name': u'a2', u'tags': {u'additionalProp3': u'a5', u'additionalProp2': u'a4', u'additionalProp1': u'a3'}}], u'valueMax': 10}}], u'to': u'2018-02-14T11:25:10.712Z', u'from': u'2018-02-14T11:05:10.712Z', u'intervalMillis': 300000}
Resp: <Response [415]>
```

Where `415` HTTP code means `Unsupported Media Type`.

How can I get the provided file in return and how should I config the path of download? Is it feasible with coding in `robotframework` or `python`?

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried setting `Content-Type` for request header as @Todor suggested:

```
${headers} =    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=${contentType}
${resp} =       RequestsLibrary.POST REQUEST    session  uri=/omc/simulator/api/generate   data=${data}   headers=${headers}
```

I still get status code `415` for both `application/octet-stream` and `application/zip` (the file has `.zip` extension) as `${contentType}`.

**EDIT 2:**

I changed the server in order to save the file into a directory, so I can use it; but since it doesn't accept my header, I still can't completely call the service. I get `415` status code, which is sent from server implying that I'm not setting right `Content-type` in my `header`.

BTW, I changed my request body as @Todor recommended:

```
${data} =       evaluate    json.dumps(json.load(open('/root/data.json', 'r')))  json
${headers} =    Create Dictionary    Content-type=${contentType}
${headers} =    evaluate    json.dumps(${headers})
${resp} =       RequestsLibrary.POST REQUEST    session  uri=/omc/simulator/api/generate   data=${data}   headers=${headers}
```

But I tried it for both application/octet-stream`and`application/zip`(the file has`.zip`extension) as`${contentType}`; still getting same error.

** EDIT 3:**

I was using wrong `Content-type` all the time; I should have used `application/json`. Considering @Todor's notes about `header` and `data`, I finally get it work.

```
${data} =       evaluate    json.dumps(json.load(open('/root/data.json', 'r')))  json
${headers} =    Create Dictionary    Content-type=application/json
${resp} =       RequestsLibrary.POST REQUEST    session  uri=/omc/simulator/api/generate   data=${data}   headers=${headers}
```

Comment: How would you do it manually - what is the request you create in a rest client/curl/python `requests` code? Succeed there, and replicate this in Robotframework;
that's just a generalization what is automated testing, but is fully applicable here. Is it feasible in the framework - for sure, it's just another way/taxonomy to express the execution steps.

Comment: Dear @Todor, I use built-in `swagger` to get the file manually; it gives me a link to download the file. I've never download it with any code.

Comment: Once again - the service logs are the first place to look at; what is printed there? What is the spec of the service - what is the format it expects in this post request?

Comment: The type of the file link it generates is irrelevant - you don't get to that point :), so don't set it to `application/zip`. When you are crafting the post request, you have to inform the service what is the type of the data **in the request's payload** - this is what the `Content-Type` header is used for. As you are sending json - judging by the example code, the correct one is _presumably_ `application/json`.

Comment: I've spotted another issue with your code, edit on my answer.

Comment: Dear @Todor, I applied your recommendation for `json` for both `body` and `header` sections; but I still get the status code of `415`.

Comment: You have to call `dumps()` only on the data, not on the headers; e.g. remove the line `${headers} =    evaluate    json.dumps(${headers})`, leaving the `headers` variable as a regular dictionary.

Comment: @Todor, you are right. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this error response you've probably missed a required header, like `content-type`; check your app's logs to be sure.
Here's how to add it:

```
# the previous code
${headers}=   Create Dictionary   Content-type=application/json
${resp} =       RequestsLibrary.POST REQUEST    session  uri=/omc/simulator/api/generate   data=${data}   headers=${headers}
```

---

There is another issue with the code; this line here:

```
${data} =       evaluate    json.load(open('/root/data.json', 'r'))   json
```

,will effectively load the provided json file, and transform it into a python object (most likely, a dictionary).
Yet, you are not supposed to send it like this in the request - it has to be serialized back into a json format (the biggest difference b/n json and string representation of python dictionaries - json does not use single quotes `'` as delimiters).

So once you've done that, you can do:

```
${data} =       evaluate    json.dumps($data)   json
```

, which will transform it back. Or, just load the file contents and not do this forth-and-back transformations.